# Nodejs on docker for a create-react-app takes >100% of cpu

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

[image: docker cpu usage]
We recently dockerized our Django/nodejs app, and it was working fine for a while. However all of a sudden the nodejs instance is taking up 150-300% of cpu at any time.

We are using docker-compose for it

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:6.12.3
RUN mkdir /code
ADD . /code/
WORKDIR /code/client/app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm rebuild node-sass --force
RUN npm run build
```

docker-compose.yml

```
 node:
    container_name: node
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/node/development/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - /code/client/app/node_modules/
    command: npm run start
    environment:
      - REACT_EDITOR=atom
```

Ive seen a few other people looking into this, changing cpu to 1, and memory to 4gb didnt fix it.

Comment: how long have you had the container running? Does it still persist when you restart your Docker daemon?

Comment: Restarted, deleted all images, uninstalled docker/reinstalled docker. None of that fixed it. The performance and battery drain is annoying, but whats really getting in the way of development is hot reloading now takes 20-30s to happen.

Comment: can you check the proccesses running in your container by doing a docker exec command? what is the size of your volume now?

Comment: @Neablis did you find a solution to this in the end?

Comment: @gen not exactly a solution, but I know the cause now. It involves using like nodemon, or watch. the way it watches for file system changes in a docker instance causes it to go crazy with CPU usage. We rewrote the watch logic to be more precise and it fixed it.

Comment: I see, thanks! That's what I concluded myself, but for now I opted for the quick and dirty solution of taking the problematic (nodejs) application out of its container and running it on the host.